# ng-autocomplete displaying '[object Object]'

Tags: angular, typescript

TS Code:

```
public TitleSelected: BaseEntity;
```

...

```
this.TitleSelected= {id: this.model.titleId, title: this.model.title};
```

HTML Code:

```
<ng-autocomplete [(ngModel)]="TitleSelected" [data]="titles" [searchKeyword]="keyword" 
       (inputChanged)='onChangeSearchTitle($event)' notFoundText="موردی یافت نشد" 
       [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate" [isLoading]="loadingTitleList" [minQueryLength]="0" 
       [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate" heading="لیست عنوان های موجود در سیستم" 
       historyIdentifier="Title_Titles_History" [historyHeading]="historyHeading" 
       historyListMaxNumber="10" placeHolder="عنوان محصول"> 
</ng-autocomplete>
```

[initialValue] is not work

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you getting this `[object object]` error but i made one stackblitz example for you.

You can check it out for your reference and work accordingly because it work at my end.

Here is the link of stackblitz : [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-autocomplete-wstktr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: "thanks" but this not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Please check the model values and their datatype if it is same as in list you provided to autocomplete, i am sure this will be the issue.

this.TitleSelected= {id: **this.model.titleId**, title: **this.model.title**};

For testing purpose you can set staic values:

```
this.TitleSelected= {id: 2, title: 'Test'};
```

Comment: thanks.
this.TitleSelected  must be read from event OnInit() on the server

Answer (score 0):

```
public TitleSelected = {id:0,title:""};
ngOnInit() {
    this.GetModel();
  }

  GetModel() {
    this.repository.getData(_URL).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.model = res as ProductVM;
        this.TitleSelected= {id: this.model.titleId, title: this.model.title};
      }
    );
  }
```

[image: Result Image]